# Can't add element to List in inner class/loop

Tags: java, android

I want to save all document IDs found in a List "names". The list is created as a global class-variable. The code is running and the documentIds are all added to the list "names", but as soon as the code leaves the inner class (OnComplete) it gets deleted again.

I know that java treats inner-classes like regular classes. But since it's an Override-class, I cant pass anything back from the class. How can I still access the change of the List?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();  

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addElements();
    }

    public void addElements(){
        db.collection("Recipes").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                                names.add(document.getId());
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                            //Log
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: try using interface class. Make a new interface class having the array list variable

Comment: It looks like you're calling Firebase to get some data, which is asynchronous. Where are you checking whether "names" has any entries? (some annotated log outputs in the sample code would make the question clearer - e.g. here it shows "names" has entries and here it shows it's empty)

Comment: I deleted the check that it has entries to make the code simpler for StackOverflow, but I had a check and document Ids get found, but I dont know how to pass them out from the inner class to the class, since I cant make any references or make the class anything else than void

Comment: I checked it. The Database returns the elements. I really checked it. Also even if I just add a random String-value to a global created String, the String gets cleared as soon as I leave the class. I know the problem is bc Java treats an Inner class like a real class, but since its an Override class I cant pass any values around.

Comment: So. I checked the following:
- Right after the names.add, the data was in the List and could be shown
- After the for loop I checked again, if the data still was in the list. it was
- After the If/else. All data still was in the List
- After the db.collection. There it wasn't in the List anymore
- I also checked with a global String what happens when I modify this string. Same as with the list.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase database calls are asynchronous. Editing a class variable from within the `OnCompleteListener` (an anonymous inner class) is fine, but you have to understand that the code in `onComplete` will not execute immediately.

The call to `db.collection(...).get().addOnCompleteListener(...);` takes your anonymous listener class and starts a background process to fetch the data (on a different thread). The function returns immediately. Once the background process has finished fetching the data, then it calls the `onComplete` method on the listener you gave it (hundreds to thousands of ms later).

For example, if you add checks as noted below, it will first print the greeting from addElements with names size = 0, then later print the greeting from onComplete with names size > 0 (assuming the query returned data). After that has happened, you can use `names` wherever needed (the values will stay there as long as the Fragment isn't destroyed), but your code has to be set up to be able to wait for that to happen.

```
public void addElements(){
    // This runs 1st
    System.out.println("Starting addElements");

    db.collection("Recipes").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                            names.add(document.getId());
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        //Log
                    }

                    // This runs 3rd! in the future when the database call is complete
                    System.out.println("HELLO FROM ONCOMPLETE");
                    printNamesSize();

                    // If you are showing "names" in a UI element, you would
                    // most likely need to call a method to update the 
                    // UI element here, once it's gotten the names
                }
            });

    // This runs 2nd, but names will be empty here (hasn't run onComplete yet)
    System.out.println("HELLO FROM ADDELEMENTS");
    printNamesSize();

    // If your code immediately tries to use names after calling addElements
    // it will still be empty, it hasn't finished the database call yet
}

void printNamesSize() {
    System.out.println("  names size = " + names.size());
}
```